# how to pass data from broadcast to service?

Tags: android, service, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

hello guys can any one tell me how to send data from broad cast to service and how to receive this data inside the service class because it dose not  work with me shuld i receive it inside ((onStartCommand)) or ((onStart)) or inside ((onReceive))
and what i should do in the Maninafest

```
String data="hello";
Intent intent1=new Intent(context,Myservice.class);
    intent1.putExtra("Data",data);
    context.startService(intent1);

//when i receive data from broad cast

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
String data="";
data=intent.getStringExtra("Phone");
Toast.makeText(this,"here is your data"+data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace 
`data=intent.getStringExtra("Phone");`
to `data=intent.getStringExtra("Data");`

Comment: actually nothing happened
i was try to change the string names in the broadcast for test
and thank you for your care
:)

Comment: I've made a simple project 4 u, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13561399/HelloBroadcastAndService.zip .

Comment: thank you very very very much for this care 
can i mail you please i need you help
this is my e-mail
poison.sniper@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you very much and nice to meet you
:)

Comment: can i ask you one more question tabbykittin please
i have contact phone number and contact name and contact id 
how can i determine to which group this contact belong if i have more than one group in my phone like favorites or family or friends 
:)